# How to Compress Files Quickly and Efficiently?

Tags: ffmpeg, compression

I have a folder containing various videos that I want to compress so that I may share it with someone who has an unstable internet connection. I tried *7z, gzip, tar, lzma, xz*, and many more for compression, but they only provide a 20-30mb reduction in size. I tried using `ffmpeg` to compress and re-encode videos, but it's really sluggish.

I also tried to compress a *.iso* file, but the results were the same.

I understand that there is a lot that goes into compression, but what should be a simple approach to minimise file size? Linux command-line tools are preferred.

Comment: What type of file are you compressing and what size? If the file is already compressed (mp3, ogg vorbis, MPEG) - you won't save much space by compressing it again. Compression algorithms look for highly repetitive data and encode it efficiently. If the data in question isn't significantly repetitive, compression won't work well.

Comment: The videos are in *.mkv format.

Comment: You won't be able to compress a video file because it is already compressed. You can transcode it using a lower resolution and bitrate but as you have found that takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Compressing images and video is "more complicated" then compressing for example text files because regular compression methods like zip etc. won't give you a very good result as you noticed yourself (user1258361's comment gives you a bit of insight here).

I would suggest to reduce the resolution, this is simple and will give you a significant reduction in size but on the downside it will reduce the quality of the pictures and videos. There are various tools for reducing the resolution via a CLI (command line interface) and this question has been asked many times, e.g. [this one for images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images-via-command-line). Just start a search and give it a try, if you run into specific problems you can ask a(nother) question. Note: depending on your HW this might not be very fast though (but neither are "good" compression algorithms, the more compression the more computation has to take place - in layman's terms).

Compressing without (significant) loss in quality is more complicated because choosing the compression method depends on the content of the image/video in regards to your requirements to quality. You will need to re-encode your files with a different compression format. There are a few [lossless compressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) but they probable won't give you sufficient results. To my knowledge there is no general answer here.

PS. Software suggestions are out of scope here on superuser.

Comment: I don't think it's off topic to ask about how to go about a specific task. "Software recommendations" are off-topic here due to how they produce highly subjective, "low-quality" answers, but if we're talking about file compression there would typically be a canonical and standard workflow for each file type. Linux command-line tools can have a significant learning curve as well.

Comment: @user1258361 I agree, I don't think either the (overall) question is off topic (just thought I mention this so it doesn't drift into becoming one because of the last sentence `Linux command-line tools are preferred.`)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to compress.

If the video file in question is already in a compressed format, there's probably nothing more you can do short of re-encoding it at a lower data rate (reducing video resolution or reducing the audio kbps rate). Again, you mentioned that re-encoding is too slow, so probably not an option.

Compression algorithms rely heavily on repetitive sequences in data. A common scheme involves building a dictionary to shorten repetitive sequences.

For example, consider the string "eabcdabcdabcd".

That can be compressed by setting a dictionary rule "f = abcd", then representing the string as "efff".

Now consider the string "abcdefghijkl".

There are no repeated sequences, so it's impossible to compress with a dictionary approach.

Compressed file formats already have much repetition removed; therefore compressing them further probably won't produce further benefits. In some cases, compressing a compressed file can increase its size (a well-known phenomenon with ZIP format).

Comment: a small addition: not all compression algorithms, especially image/audio/video just/mainly rely on repetitive (binary) sequences, there are much more complex methods involved (e.g. jpeg compression is a nice and fairly easy example). But none the less, "repetitive sequences" is a fairly good/simple example for compression in general or more especially for lossless compression